# How to see the number of finished or remaining map_async jobs?

Tags: python, ipython

I use iPython's parallel-processing facility for a big map operation. While waiting for the map operation to finish, I'd like to display to the user how many of the jobs have finished, how many are running, and how many are remaining. How can I find that information?

Here is what I do. I create a profile that uses a local engine and start two workers. In the shell:

```
$ ipython profile create --parallel --profile=local
$ ipcluster start --n=2 --profile=local
```

Here is the client Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def meat(i):
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import sys
    seconds = np.random.randint(2, 15)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return seconds

import time
from IPython.parallel import Client

c = Client(profile='local')
dview = c[:]

ar = dview.map_async(meat, range(4))
elapsed = 0
while True:
    print 'After %d s: %d running' % (elapsed, len(c.outstanding))
    if ar.ready():
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    elapsed += 1
print ar.get()
```

Example output from the script:

```
After 0 s: 2 running
After 1 s: 2 running
After 2 s: 2 running
After 3 s: 2 running
After 4 s: 2 running
After 5 s: 2 running
After 6 s: 2 running
After 7 s: 2 running
After 8 s: 2 running
After 9 s: 2 running
After 10 s: 2 running
After 11 s: 2 running
After 12 s: 2 running
After 13 s: 2 running
After 14 s: 1 running
After 15 s: 1 running
After 16 s: 1 running
After 17 s: 1 running
After 18 s: 1 running
After 19 s: 1 running
After 20 s: 1 running
After 21 s: 1 running
After 22 s: 1 running
After 23 s: 1 running
[9, 14, 10, 3]
```

As you can see, I can get the number of currently running jobs, but not the number of jobs that have completed (or are remaining). How can I tell how many of `map_async`'s jobs have finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the AsyncResult has a `msg_ids` attribute.  The outstanding jobs are the intersection of that with rc.outstanding, and the completed jobs are the difference:

```
msgset = set(ar.msg_ids)
completed = msgset.difference(rc.outstanding)
pending = msgset.intersection(rc.outstanding)
```

Comment: This does not work correctly when I use iPython's [direct interface](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html) (`c[:]`), as above. However, if I use the [task interface](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_task.html) (`c.load_balanced_view()`), it works beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: When you use the direct interface, msg_ids do not correspond to individual elements - the sequence is chunked, so there is only one task (i.e. one msg_id) per engine.  Similarly, with the task interface, you can specify `chunksize=n`, and the msg_ids will correspond to the number of *chunks*, not the number of individual elements.